# Jacobian matrix in neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-networks, jacobian

How do you calculate the Jacobian matrix using the results (weights and biases) of a neural network after training? I am working in MATLAB, if anyone has any code suggestions, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Are you asking for MATLAB code, or are you asking how the Jacobian is calculated for a neural network?

Comment: I want to know the formula to derive the Jacobian by the weights, biases from a trained neural network. If the code can be provided, I will be appreciated very much.